# ¿Cómo identificar si el SQL Server es Always On Availability Group (AG) o Always On Failover Cluster Instance (FCI)?

Tags: sql-server, sql, powershell, cluster

Necesito identificar *a través de scripting* en **PowerShell** o usando una consulta **SQL**, que tipo de rol tiene el servidor en cuestión **AG** o **FCI.** sobre el cual se corre el scipt.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer puede ser resuelto con 2 simples queries, aunque no con mucha descripción:

```
--- AG
declare @IsHadrEnabled as sql_variant  
set @IsHadrEnabled = (select SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled'))  
select @IsHadrEnabled as IsHadrEnabled,  
case @IsHadrEnabled  
when 0 then 'The Always On availability groups is disabled'  
when 1 then 'The Always On availability groups is enabled'  
else 'Invalid Input'  
end as 'Hadr' 
--- FCI
declare @IsClustered as sql_variant  
set @IsClustered = (select SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered'))  
select @IsClustered as IsClustered ,  
case @IsClustered  
when 0 then 'Not Clustered'  
when 1 then 'Clustered'  
else 'Invalid Input'  
end as 'IsClustered Status'
```